# results "join" the array does not match the date in javascript from php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a problem, when I will return results array from php to javascript in the form of date, then the show is not like I want.

PHP:

```
<?
$dates = new DateTime('2013-04-06');
$dates1=$dates->format('dm');
$arrtanggal[] = $dates1;
?>
```

JavaScript :

```
<script> 
alert(<? echo join($arrtanggal,","); ?>);
</script>
```

The result is "388".
if I change the format of the date to:

```
$dates1 = $dates->format('d/m');
```

then the result is "1.5".
I want to format into "06/04" or "06-04".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single or double quotes as follows:

```
<script> 
alert('<? echo join($arrtanggal,","); ?>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
<script> 
alert('<? echo join(",", $arrtanggal); ?>');
</script>
```

The parameters for join are:

`join( string $glue , array $pieces )`

Answer (score 0):

added single quotes to the alert and changed the date format to d/m and now it's working

```
<?php
    $dates = new DateTime('2013-04-06');
    $dates1=$dates->format('d/m');
    $arrtanggal[] = $dates1;    
print_r($arrtanggal);
?>


<script> 
alert('<?php echo join($arrtanggal,","); ?>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the / in the date format is causing the js parser to divide 6 by 4.  You have to put quotes around what you are passing in to the alert function so it is passed in as a string.